# Cesium proper way to destroy viewer

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

How in Cesium to destroy viewer?

I have few points in my viewer.entities and a model. By user clicking "Hide Cesium viewer" button - I perform

```
viewer.entities.removeAll();
viewer.destroy();
```

But by user clicking "Show Cesium viewer" button - I perform all the same adding points and model. And I see points added, but model - not.

So I think that i have missed something during destroying.

Comment: That's the correct way to destroy it.  I suspect that's probably not a well-tested code path, so you may have found a bug.  Can you put together a minimal reproduce case that can be shared?

Comment: I'm having similar issues. Does removeAll() put the entities collection (or some internal array) in a state that's not tested for on destroy()? I'm getting;

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at DataSourceDisplay._onDataSourceRemoved (Cesium.js:23)
    at DataSourceDisplay.destroy (Cesium.js:23)

Comment: I get around it by try / exception handling, but it feels a bit wrong ... :)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [emackey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/836708/emackey) reply. I have created case [cesium sandbox](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html#c=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), but not reproducing, so just

```
viewer.entities.removeAll();
viewer.destroy();
```

is fine.